# Posit workbench No module named 'jupyter_core.command'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed posit workbench just like in https://docs.posit.co/rsw/installation/. Got no error messages.
Python is in /opt/python/3.11.5/bin/.
Using RHL9.
When I try to start a jupyter notebook session I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/opt/python/3.11.5/bin/jupyter", line 5, in <module>
from jupyter_core.command import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core.command'
```

Output of /opt/python/3.11.5/bin/jupyter --version:

IPython : 8.21.0
ipykernel : 6.29.2
ipywidgets : 8.1.2
jupyter_client : 7.4.9
jupyter_core : 5.7.1
jupyter_server : 1.24.0
jupyterlab : 3.6.5
nbclient : 0.9.0
nbconvert : 7.16.0
nbformat : 5.9.2
notebook : 6.5.6
qtconsole : 5.5.1
traitlets : 5.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by chmod 755 /opt/python/3.11.5/lib/python3.11.5/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the `jupyter_core.command` module cannot be found. This could be due to a number of reasons, such as a misconfigured Python environment, or the `jupyter_core` package not being installed correctly.

You can try reinstalling the `jupyter_core` package to see if that resolves the issue. You can do this with the following command:

```
/opt/python/3.11.5/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter_core
```

This command uses the Python interpreter located at `/opt/python/3.11.5/bin/python` to reinstall the `jupyter_core` package. The `--upgrade` and `--force-reinstall` options ensure that the package is updated to the latest version and reinstalled even if it's already installed.

After running this command, try starting a Jupyter notebook session again to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer. I did exactly as it is in your post but still getting the same error.

Comment: If reinstalling `jupyter_core` didn't solve the issue, it's possible that your Python environment might be misconfigured or there might be multiple Python installations causing conflicts.
Try creating a new virtual environment, and then install Jupyter in that environment.